# SELECT & UPDATE at the same time - race condition

Tags: mysql

I'm experiencing a race condition because I'm dealing with a lot of concurrency.
I'm trying to combine these two mysql statements to execute at the same time.

I need to select a row and update the same one...

```
SELECT id_file FROM filenames WHERE pending=1 LIMIT 1;
UPDATE filenames SET pending=2 WHERE id_file=**id of select query**;
```

Another solution to the race-condition I'm experiencing would be to perform an UPDATE query where pending=1 and somehow get the ID  of the updated row, but I'm not sure if that's even possible?

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE filenames SET pending=2 WHERE pending=1 LIMIT 1

Comment: Sorry I should specify, I still need the id/result of the SELECT statement in the application.

Comment: Don't you already have the `id_file` if you're running the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: No, I want to get the id_file from the SELECT statement. But if I run two separate queries SELECT then UPDATE, that's what causes a race condition.

Comment: SQL syntax may vary depending on your DBMS, please specify what are you using. SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: have you considered using a stored procedure? (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: Can you do a sub-query, e.g. `UPDATE filenames SET pending=2 WHERE id_file=(SELECT id_file FROM filenames WHERE pending=1 LIMIT 1)`?

Comment: +1. Good question. Yes, it is possible to return the value of a column (or columns) of a row processed by an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with concurrency is one of the basic functions of [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

Wrap your queries into one transaction and tell the DBMS, that you need the row not to change in between with [`FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT id_file FROM filenames WHERE pending=1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
# do whatever you like
UPDATE filenames SET pending=2 WHERE id_file=**id of select query**;
COMMIT;
```

You can execute these statements with 4 `mysqli_query` calls, and do whatever you want in between, without need to worry about the consistency of your database. The selected row is save until you release it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the "race" condition by performing just an `UPDATE` statement on the table, allow that to identify the row to modified, and then subsequently retrieve values of columns from the row.

There's a "trick" returning values of columns, in your case, the value of the `id_file` column from the row that was just updated. You can use either the **`LAST_INSERT_ID()`** function (only if the column is integer type), or a MySQL **user-defined variable**.

If the value of the column you want to retrieve is integer, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function (which supports a BIGINT-64 value).

For example:

```
UPDATE filenames 
   SET pending = 2 
     , id_file = LAST_INSERT_ID(id_file)
 WHERE pending = 1
 LIMIT 1;
```

Following the successful execution of the UPDATE statement, you'll want to verify that at least one row was affected. (If any rows satisfied the WHERE, and the statement succeeded, we know that one row will be affected. Then you can retrieve that value, in the same session:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

to retrieve the value of `id_file` column of the last row processed by the UPDATE statement. Note that if the UPDATE processes multiple rows, only the value of *last* row that was processed by the UPDATE will be available. (But that won't be an issue for you, since there's a LIMIT 1 clause.)

Again, you'll want to ensure that a row was actually updated, before you rely on the value returned by the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

---

For non-integer columns, you can use a MySQL user-defined variable in a similar way, assigning the value of the column to a user-defined variable, and then immediately retrieve the value stored in the user-defined variable.

```
-- initialize user-defined variable, to "clear" any previous value
SELECT @id_file := NULL;

-- save value of id_file column into user-defined variable
UPDATE filenames 
   SET pending = 2 
     , id_file = (SELECT @id_file := id_file)
 WHERE pending = 1
 LIMIT 1;

-- retrieve value stored in user-defined variable
SELECT @id_file;
```

Note that the value of this variable is maintained within the session. If the UPDATE statement doesn't find any rows that satisfy the predicate (WHERE clause), the value of the user-defined variable will be unaffected... so, to make sure you don't inadvertently get an "old" value, you may want to first initialize that variable with a NULL.

Note that it's important that a subsequently fired trigger doesn't modify the value of that user defined variable. (The user-defined variable is "in scope" in the current session.)

It's also possible to do the assignment to the user-defined variable within in a trigger, but I'm not going to demonstrate that, and I would *not* recommend you do it in a trigger.